# TCP server - client, Server doesn't send date to client

Tags: java, tcp, client-server

I write simple application to communication client - server. 
Sending data from client to server works perfectly. Server calculates some stuff and tries to send to client result but it doesn't work.
here's code for client:

```
 public static void main(String argv[])  
{   
    try
    {
        View view = new View();
        view.printStartMessage();
        view.printManual();
        String input;
        String output;
        BufferedReader inFromUser = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        Socket clientSocket = new Socket("localhost", 6789);
        DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
        BufferedReader inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
        do
        {
            if (inFromServer.ready())
            {
                output = inFromServer.readLine();
                view.print(output);
            }
            input = inFromUser.readLine();    
            outToServer.writeBytes(input + "\n");
        }
        while(!"EXIT".equals(input));

        clientSocket.close();
    } 
    catch (IOException ex)
    {
        Logger.getLogger(TCPClient.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

and here's for server:

```
 public static void main(String argv[])     
{          
    try
    {
        Protocol protocol = new Protocol();
        View view = new View();
        String clientData;
        ServerSocket welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(6789);
        while(true)
        {
            Socket connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();
            BufferedReader inFromClient =
                    new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connectionSocket.getInputStream()));
            DataOutputStream outToClient = new DataOutputStream(connectionSocket.getOutputStream());
            while ((clientData = inFromClient.readLine()) != null)
            {
                view.print("Odebrano: " + clientData);
                if("EXIT".equals(clientData))
                {
                    break;
                }
                protocol.checkUsersInput(clientData);
                if(protocol.isError())
                {
                    outToClient.writeBytes(protocol.getError());
                    view.printError(protocol.getError());
                    break;
                }
                if (protocol.isResultReady())
                {
                    outToClient.writeBytes(protocol.getResult());
                    view.print(protocol.getResult());
                }
            }
            break;
        }
    } 
    catch (IOException ex)
    {
        Logger.getLogger(TCPServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

I don't know even what generates problem, client or server. 
Anyone have any idea? 
Thanks from advice.

EDIT:

Ok, problem solved. Server didn't sent end line tag so readLine method just didn't know where line have ended.

Comment: Get rid of the in.ready() test. The readLine() method will block until data is available.

Comment: When I deleted that if server cannot receive anything ;/

Comment: It can't receive anything anyway, that's why you're posting.